# User Registration page does not validate

Tags: java, php, android

```js
<?php
     
       

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password =$_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO user_info(name,age,email,password) 
    VALUES
    (?,?,?,?)");  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
     
      if($statement>0){
               $response["success"] = 1;
             }    
         else{
               $response["success"] = 0;
             }
        
         echo json_encode($response);



    ?>
```

My user registration page does not want to validate. Please advice on which side of coding between PHP text file and the android side the validation will allow the validation. Please assist further, here is the code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

final EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
final EditText Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAge);
final EditText Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
final EditText Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
final ImageButton validate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReg);

validate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
final int age = Integer.parseInt(Age.getText().toString());
final String name = Name.getText().toString();
final String email = Email.getText().toString();
final String password = Password.getText().toString();


Name.setText("");
Age.setText("");
Email.setText("");
Password.setText("");

                                                                         Response.Listener<String>responseListener=new                                    Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
try {
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
if (success) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
Register.this.startActivity(intent);
} else {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
.setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
.create()
.show();
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
};
RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, age, email,  password, responseListener);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
queue.add(registerRequest);
}
});
}

public void extBtn(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: please post your php code you're getting and what function calls you are making to make us understand what is happening and be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Clayton. Thank you for the reply, however i have been trying to post the php code and javascript detects an error and im still battling to correct it.

Comment: is there is too much PHP code, just post the relevant code you think is the code that is causing the problem, or worst case scenario you could post it to pastebin although that is less ideal (StackOverflow prefers to have code posted directly on the site).

Comment: Hope it appears now, i think the problem was me , Im just new here into posting scripts.

Comment: best practice is to do validation on both server and client side, your code on both side does not have a validation process ? so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I have added the validation code but did not work, on both side. The problem is i am unable to validate the form. Please assist anyone, i am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this part of your code:

```
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $email, $password);
$execute = $bind->mysqli_stmt_execute($bind);

 if(count($execute) > 0){
     $response["success"] = 1;
 } else{
     $response["success"] = 0;
 }       

 echo json_encode($response);
```

The `count` is to count the row in your database.

Comment: i just need to validate the input boxes, example, email using REGEXP ,password, etc, to restrict the user.